# How to json response list of queryset from different models?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-2.0

I have two models like this

```
class User(models.Model):
   user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=18)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   age = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Friend(models.Model):
   friend_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=18)
   age = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

`friend_id` and `user_id` is the same id's

```
users = User.objects.filter(user_id=1)
friends = Friend.objects.filter(friend_id=1)
```

I make the union like this

```
merge = list(users) + list(friends)
[<User: User object (1)>, <Friend: Friend object (1)>]
```

I want to do is a json response from `merge`

`HttpResponse(json.dumps(merge), content_type='application/json')`

I hope you understand my question and some idea of how to implement it

Comment: Is the User + Friend have the same id values?

Comment: @Lewis yes, is the  same id values

Answer (score 1):

I solved my question like this

```
merge = sorted( chain(users, friends) key=attrgetter('1'))

data = serializers.serialize('json', merge)
return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```